# Error using geckoddriver : Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have a selenium project using bonigarcia autodownload webdriver project. I've updated last week to the last version of selenium (4.0.0, maven repo), and the last version of bonigarcia project also (5.0.3). Now, when I try to launch my test on Firefox, I have this error :

```
Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    geckodriver --port <PORT>

For more information try --help
```

I don't find informations about this error, so could be great if someone as a workaround for this. I just see that the geckodriver used is 0.29.0 but the last one if 0.30.0

Comment: Please upate your geckodriver and try

Answer (score 2):

The --websocket-port argument was added in Geckodriver version 0.30.0, so you must use this version to avoid the error:

```
geckodriver 0.30.0 (d372710b98a6 2021-09-16 10:29 +0300)
WebDriver implementation for Firefox


USAGE:
    geckodriver [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

FLAGS:
        --connect-existing    Connect to an existing Firefox instance
    -h, --help                Prints this message
        --jsdebugger          Attach browser toolbox debugger for Firefox
    -v                        Log level verbosity (-v for debug and -vv for trace level)
    -V, --version             Prints version and copying information

OPTIONS:
    -b, --binary <BINARY>           Path to the Firefox binary
        --log <LEVEL>               Set Gecko log level [possible values: fatal, error, warn, info, config, debug, trace]
        --marionette-host <HOST>    Host to use to connect to Gecko [default: 127.0.0.1]
        --marionette-port <PORT>    Port to use to connect to Gecko [default: system-allocated port]
        --host <HOST>               Host IP to use for WebDriver server [default: 127.0.0.1]
    -p, --port <PORT>               Port to use for WebDriver server [default: 4444]
        --websocket-port <PORT>     Port to use to connect to WebDriver BiDi [default: 9222]
```